# Boostrap collapse not properly working when published (but it works locally)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, minify

I have a collapsible navbar on my website. It closes automatically and without the smooth effect that it theoretically has implemented. This is a [Bootstrap 4](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/) Jekyll website built with a gulpfile that concatenates, minifies, and uglifies the HTML, css and Javascript: http://reporteca.umh.es/
Everything but the collapsible navbar is working perfectly. The collapsible navbar actually works when loading it locally in my computer, but not when published.

I guess that the problem might be caused by the HTML/css minification process.

This is how it looks in the DOM:

```
<div class="bg-dark collapse" id="navbarHeader" style="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
        <h4 class="text-white">Acerca de</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
        <h4 class="text-white">Contacto</h4>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember: The same code is working locally, but not when published.

The Javascript files are exactly the same as those in Bootstrap 4:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Can you post the code to repro the problem instead of the link to an external site?

Comment: Thanks. I am editing the post.

Comment: Could you add the answer as a separate answer and mark it as accepted instead of editing it into the Question please?

Comment: Solved it. The problem was caused in the Gulp-Uncss process. I just added this exception to avoid the bug when publishing:

`pipe(uncss({
           html: ['_site/**/*.html'],
           ignore: ['.fade', '.collapse', '.collapse.show', '.collapsing']
       }))`


[More information](https://github.com/giakki/uncss/wiki/Using-uncss-with-Bootstrap)

Answer (score 3):

The css style for when the navbar is open seems to be missing.

I checked your index file and currently what you have is this

```
.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

Replace with this piece of code in your css file

```
.collapse {
  display: none;
  &.show {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

That should fix your issue

Comment: Thanks! Yes, your comment help me to notice that the uncss process was causing this problem by eliminating the necessary css.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

I see you have linked popper.min.js Sometimes popper is not working correctly with bootstrap 4. Remove that link and you need to download and link tether.min.js instead of popper js

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your `#navbarHeader` placed in the wrong place. It should be placed within the `.navbar` to work properly.

```html
<!-- Original place of `#navbarHeader` -->

<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark box-shadow">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mr-2"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle></svg><strong>Reporteca</strong></a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    </div>

    <!-- New place of `#navbarHeader`, without `.show` -->
    <div class="bg-dark collapse" id="navbarHeader" style="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
                    <h4 class="text-white">Acerca de</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
                    <h4 class="text-white">Contacto</h4>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it doesn't fix it.